# React - How to build a simple button-application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm currently building a new React application, and am having a bit of trouble understanding the basics; I'm a complete beginner.

Bascially, what I need to do is have a button that, when clicked, opens up a container. Here is my thought process:

1. Create a main component, named "App". Within App, return a button.
2. The button, when clicked, should call another component that opens the container.

Some of what I have started on the code so far:

```
class handleClick extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isClicked: false
        };


        render(){
            return(

            );
        }
    }
}

function App(props){
    //HAVE A COMPONENT TO TRIGGER THE CONTAINER

    return(
        <div>
            <button>
                Open photo entry dialog
            </button>
        </div>


    );
```

I have no idea what to do. Any logic tips?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by a container? another div or another component.

Comment: This might help https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier So for example, when the button is clicked, I want a square box to open up, and within the box, I want there to be a place where the user can enter some text and hit enter.

Comment: Check [this](https://daveceddia.com/open-modal-in-react/), it’s called modal dialog. And you should follow a simple tutorial to understand how react works, for example a click handler should be a function instead of a class!

Answer (score 0):

To create model popup from parent to child component. Sample [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/model-popup-o1z0p) App using `react-bootstrap`

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

Sample Code

App.js

```
import Model from "./Model";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { status: false };
  handleClick = e => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ status: !prev.status }));
  };
  render() {
    const { status } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click to opent model</button>
        {status && <Model status={status} handleClick={this.handleClick} />}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Model.js

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Model({ handleClick, status }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={status} onHide={handleClick}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClick}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClick}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

https://o1z0p.csb.app/

Comment: @Darrel Gulseth check this example created for you.